# Laggy CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to size up some container on my site using CSS3-animation.

This is my Container:

```css
.new-place-wrapper {
  background: #004682;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
  animation-name: newplace;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  max-height: 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8888;
}

@keyframes newplace {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 9999px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="new-place-wrapper" data-equalizer>
  <div class="new-place-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
  <div class="inner-place-left" data-equalizer-watch>
    <span>Wir sind umgezogen!</span>
    Ab sofort finden Sie uns hier:
    <address>
      <strong>Company</strong><br>
      STREET 123<br>
      CITY<br><br>
      PHONE
    </address>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-place-right" data-equalizer-watch>
    <a class="button radius" href="#">VCF-Karte</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically the animation works quite fine but there is a strange lagging at the beginning. Firstly the container gets higher juddering. After a moment the animation goes on very smooth.

[Check it out over here!](http://www.edc-daten.de/index.php?tsoid=headline) (Wait 5 Seconds!)

Comment: I think that I can't see the problem. Is it happening in the snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why transitions for some CSS properties are slow and none fluent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347701/why-transitions-for-some-css-properties-are-slow-and-none-fluent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decrease the max height to better see the animation.

```css
.new-place-wrapper {
  background: #004682;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
  animation-name: newplace;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  max-height: 0px;
  padding:  0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8888;
}

@keyframes newplace {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 309px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="new-place-wrapper" data-equalizer>
  <div class="new-place-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
  <div class="inner-place-left" data-equalizer-watch>
    <span>Wir sind umgezogen!</span>
    Ab sofort finden Sie uns hier:
    <address>
      <strong>Company</strong><br>
      STREET 123<br>
      CITY<br><br>
      PHONE
    </address>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-place-right" data-equalizer-watch>
    <a class="button radius" href="#">VCF-Karte</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

I have read about transitions a bit and the main conclusion is that, you should avoid transitioning width/height, left/right/top/bottom and instead use the transform property.

These answers might help you:

[Why transitions for some CSS properties are slow and none fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347701/why-transitions-for-some-css-properties-are-slow-and-none-fluent)

[How to smoothly animate height in CSS or Javascript on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761703/how-to-smoothly-animate-height-in-css-or-javascript-on-mobile-devices)