# Animation CSS/JS Jerky on Android and sometime PC

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I create a Periodic Table Apps and I create an animation where Element move from initial position to center of window, but transitions are Jerky. To do this I Create a Copy of this Element (clicked) and change is Class.

[image]

Animation are made from CSS (updating class which has other Left/Top/Translate values) and few are coming from JS (for example : x.style.left = y)

I also tried to create CSS ROOT values and update them with JS, but same problem. I Also tried to remove maximum JS which is not necessary. Tried Request Animation Frame "everywhere" too.

I am not using Plugins, it's a VanillaJS App made With Isotope. Do you know why is this laggy ?
Are there too many elements in my DOM ? Or Maybe i Am doing wrong ? Love this kind of transition, so I really Want to know how i can optimise it !

Here is a [Link](https://lucasarts.fr/applications/periodixv2/assets/js/core.js) for my Project JavaScript (Might be updated frequently).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problems with jerky/laggy animation with a slider.

The conclusion was that animation should be done with `transform` properties, not with top/bottom/left/right and neither with `margin` or  `padding`. 
Here are two posts I found that explain the problem: 
[Laggy CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432531/laggy-css-animation) 
[Why transitions for some CSS properties are slow and none fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347701/why-transitions-for-some-css-properties-are-slow-and-none-fluent)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer ! Yeah a read that few days ago, tried a bit (still had problem), but i didn't replace all Left/Top etc by translate, maybe i should tried.

I am using Isotope, so element are absolute with Left/Top position, I will need to work on this tho

Comment: the elements can still have those properties based on what I could gather. 
But the animation needs to happen with `transform`. I know, it's really complicated, especially when you need to change existing code to work.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I Will try to change all animation Left/Top... by Transform properties. How should i do with Heiht/Width properties ? Scale is the only way ?

Comment: Edit : I Tried to change all transition Top/Left etc by Transform translate and it's working ! Thank you very much
Now I have another trouble : Width and Height, those properties are still jerky, I tried with RequestAnimationFrame, but I still have problem tho :(

Comment: you can also use `transform` to change the size, I believe for size you need to use `transform: scale`. You can read about it here: [2D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

Comment: Yeah I know but using Scale Will change Scale Content too. Maybe I need to calculate Scale(0.X) for content to make it lower, but not the best way i guess :(

Comment: I'm not sure about that either unfortunately. My best guess would be that you could reverse the scale within the child items. So if you give a container a scale of 0.5 to half it, give the child a scale of 2.

Comment: Thx for answer. I'll check, but I Hope I'll be able to find a better solution,